# I cant access all my SharePoint 2010 sites? everything is down

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I tried creating a new web application but an unexpected error occured and suddently all my sites were off.I tried restarting my IIS but i still cant find get the sites up

Comment: Is your Central Administration site working? Are WebApplication  pools in IIS started?

Comment: Yes my Central admin site  is working and all my Webapplication pools are started

Comment: How many servers in farm? what error you are seeing in the Event Log / ULS logs? Check if Database Server is up and All Content DBs are Online?

Comment: Can you post the full error - is it IIS/.NET or SharePoint error page you are seeing?  Enable debugging error in web.config (CallStack="true"; customErrors mode="off"; compiliation debug="true")  This will give you more verbose .NET errors.

Comment: I have four servers on my farm one for production and development and same goes for sql instances,i cant view any log files all i see is .Usage file path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS" all content db are online because this is a sharePoint machine i will be able to log in any way

Comment: **Error
An unexpected error has occurred.

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: bdfaa2a9-5658-477a-8b21-19e728a36261**                                          That is the full error and it is  the SharePoint error  PAGE,i have tried to add new  web application but i couldn't add, but now after i restarted the server i can see that the site is added and even on the IIS is hosted. giving that i couldn't create the web application i am at a loss i am strictly a beginner in SharePoint

Comment: Do you have many web applications? Sound's to me that you got a time-out while trying to create a new web-application. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112358/not-able-to-create-web-application-in-sp-2013/112364#112364

Comment: if you can then run the below powershell and share the result....Merge-SPLogFile -Path "C:\Logs\FarmMergedLog.log" -Correlation   give the current correlation id.

Comment: what is the issue, you cannot access any site or you having issue to creating new webapplication or browsing it?

Comment: You may also want to verify that the SQL server isn't out of disk space.

Comment: @user199952,Yes i have many web applications, even though it was maybe a limited time out i cannot view any site at all and i have deleted the site, i tested by creating a sample web application again but even the newly created web app/site throws the same error so i don't think it can be a time out issue

Comment: @Waqas Sarwar MCSE i cannot access any site at all and when i browse to any site i get the same error so now the main thing is to get all the site running and working,i also changed the SecurityTokenServiceApplication as this was giving issues and by editing the web config and enabling windows and Anonymous Authentication, What else can i do to solve this problem.

Comment: @nsturdivant my  drive on the server  was full yes but i have deleted necessary files, can a full disk actually make the whole sites to crash totally?

Comment: It absolutely can. There are various symptoms associated with a full hard drive on the SQL server hosting the configuration and/or content databases including the famous "the farm is not accessible" error as well as generic 503 errors. If you've freed up some disk space on the SQL server and have kick-started any stopped application pools, you should be good to go. Are you up and running at this point?

Comment: wow thanks it makes sense now I didn't know that I am a beginner,Unfortunately no I am not up and running. what caused the crash is that My Clients HDD(I don't know how they set up their RAID) crashed probably because of space when I was creating a new web app, I am waiting on them to do backup and Restore and maybe the sites will be up and running if not then ill have to reinstall SharePoint 2010 while preserving the content databases for each site, I hope this will work, I did try what you suggested but there are no changes, Is there another solution I can test?