# Application error when access /_admin/extendvs.aspx, Error=The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can anybody help me resolving this error **"Application error when access /_admin/extendvs.aspx, Error=The system cannot find the path specified"**

```
Stack Trace
```

> Application error when access /_admin/extendvs.aspx, Error=The system
>   cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPMetabaseObject.Provision()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebSite.Provision()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionWebApplication(String
>   webApplicationName, String applicationPoolName, SPIisSettings[]
>   settings, Boolean adminWebApp)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSitesAsAdministrator()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSites()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ExtendVirtualServerPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The system cannot find the path
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPMetabaseObject.Provision()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebSite.Provision()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionWebApplication(String
>   webApplicationName, String applicationPoolName, SPIisSettings[]
>   settings, Boolean adminWebApp)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSitesAsAdministrator()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSites()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ExtendVirtualServerPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The system
>   cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.SetInfo()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.CommitChanges()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPMetabaseObject.Provision()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebSite.Provision()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProvisioningAssistant.ProvisionWebApplication(String
>   webApplicationName, String applicationPoolName, SPIisSettings[]
>   settings, Boolean adminWebApp)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSitesAsAdministrator()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.ProvisionIisWebSites()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Provision()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ExtendVirtualServerPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   ASP._admin_extendvs_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\5d20eb63\2f586958\App_Web_extendvs.aspx.76acb6ce.xay8bb9p.0.cs:line
>   0     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112358/not-able-to-create-web-application-in-sp-2013, check this link

Comment: i am not getting "request timeout error" but file not found error, please take a look at stack trace.